# camel-salesforce-maven-plugin generates code that does not compile

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce, code-generation, maven-plugin

when running pom.xml with

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-salesforce-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>camel-sforce</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <version>44.0</version>
        <clientId>${my.clientId}</clientId>
        <clientSecret>${my.clientSecret}</clientSecret>
        <userName>${my.username}</userName>
        <password>${my.password}</password>
        <loginUrl>${my.loginUrl}</loginUrl>
        <packageName>com.my.entities4camel</packageName>
        <includes>
            <include>Task</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the generated code does not compile 
because of the code like

```
 private Account_Lookup What;

    @JsonProperty("What")
    public Account_Lookup getWhat() {
        return this.What;
    }

    @JsonProperty("What")
    public void setWhat(Account_Lookup What) {
        this.What = What;
    }
    private rtms__CarrierPayment__c_Lookup What;

    @JsonProperty("What")
    public rtms__CarrierPayment__c_Lookup getWhat() {
        return this.What;
    }

    @JsonProperty("What")
    public void setWhat(rtms__CarrierPayment__c_Lookup What) {
        this.What = What;
    }
```

it seems that any field that has Salesforce "polymorphism" (able to reference any type of Entity) causes the issue.

`Task` just simplest example.

Another thing that might be important: I run on top of an installed package 
the fields with prefix `rtms__` are from the managed package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

It's a bug.

And it is solved.

Fix will be released in the next cycle.

***Great thanks and kudos goes to the Camel Dev Team and Contributors.***

**Thank you guys!!!**

here is the ticket in the Camel Jira

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12963